# Change "value" of a <input> while clicking on query result, while more than one record

Tags: php, javascript

I have a script that would change the value of a input field:

```php
    <script language="javascript">
    function klientid() {
    var getid = document.getElementById("getidfromsearch");//results
    var klid = document.getElementById("idklienta"); //input field
    if(getid != "0") {
    klid.value = getid.textContent;
    }
    </script>
```

a search engine and this is how results are printed:

```php
    <?php
    while($rowmilion = mysqli_fetch_array($resultmilion)) {
    ?>
    <a href="javascript:klientid()">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; width: 160px; text-align:right;">ID:</td>
    <td style="width:200px;" id="getidfromsearch"><?php echo $rowmilion['id']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </a>
    <?php } ?>
```

Now, when as the result there is only one record and I click on the link, it does change the value of a input field fine.

When result consists of more than one record, whichever link I would click, it will always get the value from the first record for example:

```php
ID: 100
ID: 200
ID: 300
```

So when I click on the third position, it will still change the value of a input field to 100 instead of 300.

I quess, this is because all records get the same "ID"... But still, I can't make it work.

Comment: I would set the id to the tr-tag. It makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give an unique ID for each result or it will screw up your getElementById search.

Your JS code :

```
<script language="javascript">
    function klientid(domElmtId) {// ** I added a parameter
        var getid = document.getElementById(domElmtId);//results
        var klid = document.getElementById("idklienta"); //input field
        if(getid !== null) {// ** This is better
            klid.value = getid.textContent;
        }
    </script>
```

Your Php code

```
<?php
    $count = 0;//** I added a variable to give each result a different ID
    while($rowmilion = mysqli_fetch_array($resultmilion)) {
    ?>
    <a href="javascript:klientid('result<?php echo $count; ?>')">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; width: 160px; text-align:right;">ID:</td>
    <td style="width:200px;" id="result<?php ?>"><?php echo $rowmilion['id']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </a>
    <?php 
    $count += 1;//** to make different IDs
} ?>
```